# How to add video chat capability to my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, videochat

I've been googling about how to accomplish oneline chat for rails application and I've implemented a text chat version using Juggernaut. But for video chat, I only find flash&red5 might be a solution for me, but it's flash and java, which I'm relatively not good at. Is there a better solution?

Comment: can you write ruby code and have it run on the Java VM using JRuby? I think you can access Java Libraries through ruby that way as well. Also learn java :)

Answer (score 4):

I have researched this a little and the options are not great.

There are some nice-looking packages that cost real money. Tokbox.com, ooVoo (http://www.oovoo.com, looks free at first but free version has limits), VideoWhisper.com looks interesting -- they seem to sell a 2-way video chat package for a one-time fee, but it is PHP-based.

A simple Flash-based solution is definitely a good way to go. Flash has good video support and virtually everyone has it installed already. It's not that hard to learn enough Flash basics to do a simple 2-way video chat (see http://www.derekentringer.com/blog/fms-video-chat/ for an example of a trivial video chat script that is something like 30 lines of code). And you don't need to learn Java to use Red5 unless you want to customize it -- Red5 is the open-source video streaming server that makes it so you don't need to buy really a expensive Adobe Media Streaming server system. You just need to learn enough to set it up and get it running.

I'm certain there's an open-source or low-cost Flash script out there that handles a basic 2-way video chat, but I have yet to find it. If anyone does, please post it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rails implementation of tokbox:
http://github.com/njacobeus/tokboxer/

Comment: I looked at it, and their site looks great, and there is a lot of developer support, but when we tried their service, the video and audio quality was really bad. Google Talk video was much better between the same machines. Is tokbox available only in certain regions (we need it to work in Japan and between Japan and the US)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Raydash. There is a rails gem available at https://github.com/gersh/Raydash-Ruby-on-Rails. You just need to register at http://www.raydash.com to use it.